# How does angular "$uibModalInstance.close(data)" work?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-modal

The official documentation of AngularJS does not contain anything that describes how `$uibModalInstance.close` works, in the following code fragment, `scope.close` is a method used to close the modal window and pass an object to the caller controller

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp');

app.controller('ModalController', ['$uibModalInstance', modalControllerFn]);

function modalControllerFn($uibModalInstance) {
    var scope = this;
    
    // some data object
    scope.data = {key1: "value1", key2: "value2"};
    
    scope.close = function() {
        $uibModalInstance.close(scope.data);
    }
}
```

#### Question (1)

Does passing anything belonging to the modal scope using `$uibModalInstance.close` (non-literal value, i.e: `scope.x`) prevent angular garbage collection from destroying the entire modal scope? Is this a scenario for causing memory leaks?

#### Question (2)

How does angular `$uibModalInstance.close(data)` exactly work?

Answer (score 10):

Please have a look at the JavaScript example on Angular UI Bootstrap's website here:  [Angular UI Bootstrap Modal](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal)

Scroll down just a bit and click the JavaScript tab to see the code.

The important part is this:

```
modalInstance.result.then(function (selectedItem) {
  $scope.selected = selectedItem;
}, function () {
  $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
});
```

Above, the `selectedItem` variable is what is passed into:

```
$uibModalInstance.close(rightHereGetsPassedAsResult)
```

Comment: Thanks for your time, but, this does not answer any of my questions, may be you are trying to answer indirectly ? please elaborate more

Comment: Ah got it, you are trying to explain how to use it, but this is not my question

Answer (score 3):

`var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({template:tmpl, controller: ctrlr})`

In the above code $uibModal.open() returns a promise to be resolved or rejected.

If it is resolved, when the user clicks your 'ok' button, you may have a statement that does something afterwards like..

`modalInstance.result.then(function (data) {
    console.log('user clicked ok', data)
})`

On the $scope of the controller for your modal instance you will have a function as the ng-click for your 'ok' button

`$scope.ok = function() {
    $uibModalInstance.close(data);
}`

The data you pass to $uibModalInstance.close(data) in your $scope function is returned as the data result in the aforementioned statement.